# SAS proc timeseries: aggregate over a specified intervale

Tags: sas

I want to use PROC TIMESERIES to aggregate data over a specified interval. In particular, I want to aggregate over a 60seconds window, starting from 30 seconds over the minute.

I have tried with the following code:

```
proc timeseries data=test out= test_30shift;
id datetime interval=sec60 accumulate=first setmissing=missing align=middle start = '18apr1997.00:05:30'dt end = '19apr1997.00:00:30'dt;
```

var bid;
   run;

I have also tried with ALIGN=BEGINNING.

The result is similar to following code:

```
proc timeseries data=test out= test_noshift;
id datetime interval=sec60 accumulate=first setmissing=missing align=beg start = '18apr1997.00:05:00'dt end = '19apr1997.00:00'dt; 
var bid;
run;
```

How do I achieve aggregation over an interval starting where I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is close.  You need to make the `interval=sec60.31`.

```
data test;
format dt datetime19.;

do dt = "01JAN2015:00:00:00"dt to "02JAN2015:00:00:00"dt;
    x = rannor(123);
    output;
end;
run;

proc timeseries data=test out=test2;
id dt interval=sec60.31 accumulate=first align=beginning;
var x;
run;
```

[image]

The mid-point of 0 - 59 is at 29 seconds, so we have to shift 31 seconds to start at MM:30.